# Cryptography in Japan before Meiji

Tags: mathematics, japan, cryptology

I have a question related to Japan History and cryptography record. As you may know, Meiji is the period in Japan between 1868 and 1912, in which occidental reforming was performed.

After (and through) this period I know there's some record of cryptography techniques (in war) such as the *purple machine*. But I'm kind of curious about **other cryptography techniques**, maybe more rustic, and older, **not influenced** by occidental 'modern' war techniques.

Do you guys know anything about this? Thank you in advance.